# How to move "Files [Integer].jpg" to "Folder [Integer]" obeying numerical correspondence?

Tags: batch

I have files stored in a directory as follows:

```
Photo 1.jpg  
Photo 2.jpg  
Photo 3.jpg
```

Within the same folder I have a series of subfolders that already exist and have other files within them:

```
 Group 1  
 Group 2  
 Group 3
```

Is there a way to move the files to the subfolder that contains the same number within the name?

Comment: What have you tried already ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I can't comment right now</s>, so I can't ask if you are using Windows or Linux, or you have Python installed or not, therefore, I will write the scripts for both of them,

First, PowerShell

```
# Get all .jpg files in the current directory.
$all_files = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg

# Iterate through the list of files.
foreach ($file in $all_files) {

    # Extract the number from the file name.
    $number = $file.Name.Split(" ")[1].Split(".")[0]

    
    # Print a message to the console.
    Write-Host "Copying $file to Group $number/"


    # Copy the file to the new folder.
    Copy-Item $file "Group $number"
}
```

Then, Python

```python
import glob
import shutil
import os

# Get All .jpg
all_files = glob.glob("*.jpg")
for file in all_files:

    # Get that Number
    number = file.split(" ")[1].split(".")[0]

    print(f"Copying {file} to Group {number}/")
    
    # if the folder, in case, do not exists, create it
    if not os.path.exists(f"Group {number}"):
        os.mkdir(f"Group {number}")
    
    # copy the file
    shutil.copy2(file, f"Group {number}")
```

Note that, in the python script, I'm using `shutil.copy2()` function, as it preserves metadata like date/time.
Also, I'm copying instead of moving, as asked to prevent any unforeseen disasters. you can delete the jpgs afterwards.

Though, if you are confident, you can replace the last line

```python
shutil.copy2(file, f"Group {number}")
```

with

```python
os.rename(file, f"Group {number}/{file}")
```

AND, add this import at the top

```python
import os
```

Then, for the powershell, replace this line

```
# Copy the file to the new folder.
Copy-Item $file "Group $number"
```

with this,

```
# Move the file to the new folder.
Move-Item -Path $file -Destination "Group $number"
```

### Now to run these

For *powershell*, create a file name `copy_script.ps1`, beware of the extension, it should not be `.txt`, but `.ps1`. Open it in Notepad, and paste the code as above. *Right click* the script and select *Run With Powershell*, it should be done by now

Now, For python, if you have installed python, then you should have known how to run. But if not, then download and install the latest Python from [Python's Website](https://www.python.org/downloads/). While installing, be sure to check *"Add To PATH"*. Then create a file named `copy_script.py`, (again not `.txt` but `.py`), paste the python code as above, then simply double-click it to run it. Thing should be done by now.

If you don't know how to confirm if it's `.ps1` or `.py` and not `.txt`, see this [How to Enable Filename Extensions in Windows](https://pureinfotech.com/show-file-extensions-windows-11/#:%7E:text=To%20show%20file%20extensions%20on%20Windows%2011%2C%20open%20File%20Explorer,for%20known%20file%20types%E2%80%9D%20option.)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for that HarshNJ. How do I use either of these?

Comment: Keep in mind, OP asks to move the files, not to copy them. You may want to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: I'm copying files, instead of moving, to prevent any unforeseen disasters. OP can delete all the jpgs after checking if all files are _copied_ correctly. I will add this note

Comment: I will edit the question to add run instructions to the answer @PioShelby

Comment: Thanks HarshNJ.  I like your idea to copy the files and I can delete them when I am satisfied that the operation has run correctly.  And thank you for your instructions on how to run them.  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much PioShelby, from now on, I can comment on questions. If did solve your questions, please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

**[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder\Where\JPGs\Are" 2>nul || exit /b

for /f delims^= %%i in ('dir /a: /b /a:-d *.jpg ^| findstr /e [0-9]\.jpg
    ')do set "_dir=%%~ni" && call move /y "%%~i" "%%_dir:photo=group%%"
```

---

**[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** + **[script](/questions/tagged/script)**

```bash
Set-Location "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder\Where\JPGs\Are" 

Get-ChildItem .\*.jpg | ForEach { 
    Move-Item $_ -Destination ($_.BaseName).Replace("Photo","Group")
   }
```

---

**[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** + **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**

```bash
 cd "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder\Where\JPGs\Are" ; dir .\*.jpg | % {Move $_ -Destination ($_.BaseName).Replace("Photo","Group")}
```

---

**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** + **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

```all-bat
PowerShell -Nol -NoP -Ex -By "gci .\*.jpg | ? { Move $_ -Dest ($_.BaseName).Replace('Photo','Group')}"
```

---

**[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**

```bash
@cd "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder\Where\JPGs\Are" && @for /f delims^= %i in ('dir /a: /b /a:-d *.jpg ^| findstr /e [0-9]\.jpg')do @(%ComSpec% /v /c "set "_dir=%~ni" && call move /y "%~i" "!_dir:photo=group!"")
```

---

**Obs.:** Consider testing the behavior using ***`Move-Iten ... -WhatIf`***:

**[script](/questions/tagged/script)** + **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

```all-bat
cd "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder\Where\JPGs\Are" ; gci .\*.jpg | % { 
    Move $_ -Destination ($_.BaseName).Replace("Photo","Group") -WhatIf
   }
```

---

**[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)** + **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

```all-bat
cd "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder\Where\JPGs\Are" ; gci .\*.jpg | % {Move $_ -Dest ($_.BaseName).Replace("Photo","Group") -wi }
```

---

**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** + **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

```all-bat
PowerShell -Nol -NoP -Ex -By "gci .\*.jpg | ? { Move $_ -Dest ($_.BaseName).Replace('Photo','Group') -wi}"
```

---

---

> *I have files stored in a directory as follows:*
>
> ```all-bat
> Photo 1
> Photo 2
> Photo 3
> ```
>
> *Within the same `folder I` have a series of subfolders that already exist and have other files within them:*
>
> ```all-bat
> Group 1
> Group 2
> Group 3
> ```
>
> - A simple replace for a variable with the name of `%var:file=folder%` can serve you precisely.
>
> - In **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**
>
> ```bash
> >$Folder="Photo 1"
> >$Folder
> Photo 1
>
> >$Folder=$Folder.Replace("Photo","Group")
> >$Folder
> Group 1
> ```
>
> - In **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**
>
> ```bash
> >set "_var=Photo 1"
> >echo\%_var%
> Photo 1
>
> >set "_var=%_var:Photo=Group%"
> >echo\%_var%
> Group 1
> ```

---

**Additional resources:**

Refer: **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

- [`Replace`](https://ss64.com/ps/move-item.html)
- [`ForEach`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)
- [`Move-Item`](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [`Get-Childitem`](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [**PowerShell Basics: Don't Fear Hitting Enter with `-WhatIf`**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/powershell-basics-don-t-fear-hitting-enter-with-whatif/ba-p/353579)

---

Refer: **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**

- [`cd /d`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Move /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [How-to: Edit/Replace text within a Variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)